# fail2ban restarts immediately after stopping

Tags: ubuntu, fail2ban

It seems like fail2ban is restarted immediately after calling `fail2ban-client stop`. Here's a part of the log file

> 2016-08-29 22:51:42,164 fail2ban.jail           [2886]: INFO    Jail 'apache-overflows' stopped
>
> 2016-08-29 22:51:42,168 fail2ban.server         [2886]: INFO    Exiting Fail2ban
>
> 2016-08-29 22:51:43,300 fail2ban.jail           [3235]: INFO    Jail 'apache-overflows' started

Also `fail2ban-client status` returns

```
Status
|- Number of jail:  11
`- Jail list:   apache-auth,...
```

Comment: `systemctl stop fail2ban`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**fail2ban** is probably being managed by **systemd**

On my Ubuntu 16.04 system, the fail2ban service file looks like this:

```
# /lib/systemd/system/fail2ban.service
[Unit]
Description=Fail2Ban Service
Documentation=man:fail2ban(1)
After=network.target iptables.service firewalld.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client -x start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client stop
ExecReload=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client reload
PIDFile=/var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.pid
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) `Restart=always` means this:

> If set to always, the service will be restarted regardless of whether it exited cleanly or not, got terminated abnormally by a signal, or hit a timeout.

So you're `fail2ban` service is **automatically restarting** when you stop it.

If you want to **stop** it you'll need to use `systemctl`

```
systemctl stop fail2ban
```

You can **start** it again with

```
systemctl start fail2ban
```